# Creating a drop down as user types in search?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a mobile website, where there is a search box, and let's say we enter a couple of letters "ad", it will search a list in the view model for items containing "ad" and provide a drop down underneath the search, and for it to change as more letters are typed.

I am completely stumped on this, as a beginner programmer, at the moment I have a SelectList in my view model, that displays everything on my select list in the view.

I have tried of different ways to do this, for example having a partial view with the drop down list, using jquery to post the value entered in the search, and display the partial view that will contain a brand new list, but there must be a more efficient way of doing this?

I have also tried playing around with Json, but I can't seem to figure out how to keep the previously generated list in the event the user enters more letters.

Thanks guys, please let me know if I need to provide more info, or code samples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked out http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: hey thanks, as I said I am new so there are a lot of these interesting functions I did not know about, this looks good, but if I were to settle for the suggested keyword, how would I post the ID of the selected item? It's not exactly a selectlist :S

Comment: this enhances a normal html select element

Answer (score 0):

A different alternative might be [jQuery Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) plugin. It is awesome, you should give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Find a nice demo here http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/ for autocomplete